# Search Server 2010 - reference error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-2010, episerver

Im running Search Server 2010 from a virtual machine and it works good so far. On my development machine (win xp 32bit), the thought is to query the search server with a web service. Problem is that when i try to start the site, i get the following error:

`Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.`

`Exception Details: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Server.Search' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.`

I copied the dll-file from virtual server after the installation of Search Server. Added it as a reference and its there in the bin-catalog. Compiles with no errors. The site is not a sharepoint site, but a EPiServer Site.

Any help is most appreciated.

/Mattias

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the correct way to add the reference is via WEB reference...